# How to get the for loop output of Python script to Email with Outlook

Tags: python

How to get the for loop consolidated output in the email body?

```
import win32com.client as client

j=range(1,9)
for i in j:
print(i)

outlook=client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
message=outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.Display()
message.To ="xxxxx"
message.CC = "xxxxx"
message.Subject="test"
html_body="""
               <div>
                <p>i</p>
                </div>
                """

message.HTMLBody= html_body
message.Send()
print("mail sent ")
```

the output I am getting is sending different mails to each element.

```
2
mail sent 
4
mail sent 
6
mail sent 
8
mail sent 
10
mail sent 
12
mail sent 
14
mail sent 
16 
mail sent
```

The output I need

```
 2
 4
 6
 8
 10
 12
 14
 16 
Mail Sent
```

Comment: You do know that you need to indent your code for any code blocks, like things to do inside "for"?

Comment: In the output i need only a single mail 
 2
 4
 6
 8
 10
 12
 14
 16

with the above output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move `mail sent` out of the for loop

```
import win32com.client as client

num = ""
j = range(1, 9)
for i in j:
    print(i)
    num += str(i) + "/n"

    outlook = client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    message.Display()
    message.To = "xxxxx"
    message.CC = "xxxxx"
    message.Subject= "test"
    html_body= f"{num}mail sent"

    message.HTMLBody = html_body
    message.Send()

print("mail sent")
```

## Edit

As said in the comment, the Original Poster does not want to send multiple emails. In that case, we don't even need to use the for loop.

```
import win32com.client as client

num = "\n".join(str(x) for x in range(1, 9))

outlook = client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.Display()
message.To = "xxxxx"
message.CC = "xxxxx"
message.Subject= "test"
html_body= f"{num}\nmail sent"

message.HTMLBody = html_body
message.Send()

print("mail sent")
```

Comment: I am getting number of Emails with "I" in the Body. 
Please assist.
The above code is not working as expected I could say

Comment: You could change the ``html_body`` into the anything that you want to include in the body section. For example, set it to ``html_body = "Hello"`` and the emails will have Hello instead of I in the body. And it also supports HTML formatting like ``html_body = "<i>Hello</i>"`` the Hello will be in italics.

Comment: I Need to get the value of I which is the value in for loop in the Email body

Comment: Did you mean the lowercase i?

Comment: Sorry ,
what I mean is the output of complete for loop in each iteration , we will get some consolidated output Right. So what I need is I need the complete output in the Email Body

Comment: @Ishika I have updated the code. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Getting the below error

    num.append(str(i) + "/n")

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @Ishika Whoops. I have fixed the problem. Check again if it works.

Comment: sorry again . I am getting Multiple Emails for each Iteration.
I Want the Consolidated Output means : From First Loop to the last loop output in a single Email . 
when i change the Message.send() out of for loop 
It leads to generating the Email drafts not the output as expected .

Comment: @Ishika Sorry but what do you mean by "generating the Email drafts not the output as expected"? What exactly do you mean by "email drafts" and what "output" do you want? Please clarify the problem to make it easier for both.

Comment: I Want to get the Output of For loop in The Email body -- Complete output of for loop in the single Email 
Not sending multiple emails for each iteration

Comment: @Ishika Ok. We are done. Let's see if it works now!

Comment: "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found " Getting this error again

Comment: @Ishika Ok, too many edits so far. But I promise, this is the last one! Please check again this time.

Comment: Sorry ,Same Error 

num = "\n".join(range(1, 9))

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: @Ishika ``num = "\n".join(str(x) for x in range(1, 9))``

Comment: thank you . 
Finally i can able to get the required output 
I appreciate your effort for helping me 
Thanks again

Comment: @Ishika Thank you, too! Could I have the tick ✅ now? 